# Filter an array and retrieve only strings starting with highest number

Tags: python, arrays, linux

I've got the following sample-array:

```
arr = ["0001_xyz_01", "0001_xyz_02", "0001_xyz_03", "0002_xyz_01", "0002_xyz_02", "0002_xyz_03", "0003_xyz_01", "0003_xyz_02", "0003_xyz_03"]
```

From this array I'd like to create a new array containing only strings which begins with the highest number. So the new array would look like:

```
new_arr = ["0003_xyz_01", "0003_xyz_02", "0003_xyz_03"]
```

Note that:

- When building the `new_arr` only the first 4 characters should be looked at - the rest of the string must be ignored.
- The order of the items in `arr` may change.
- The number of items in `arr` may change.

I guess I can use `filter`, but I'm not sure how:

```
new_arr = filter(lambda x: <some-filtering-here>, arr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a pretty solution, but you could try this...

```
>>> new_arr = [x for x in arr if x.startswith(sorted([y[:4] for y in arr])[-1])]
['0003_xyz_01', '0003_xyz_02', '0003_xyz_03']
```

To explain:

- `sorted([y[:4] for y in arr])[-1]` sorts a list of the first 4 characters of each string and picks the highest value.
- `[x for x in arr if x.startswith(...)]` is a list comprehension picking out the strings starting with this highest value.

Comment: +1 for explanation. I like your solution because, in contrast to the other solutions, it doesn't use `split`.

Comment: Thank you! Glad if my answer was of some use.

Comment: Sorry, I was too fast. Something is wrong. It outputs `['0003_xyz_03', '0003_xyz_03', '0003_xyz_03']`, when it should be `['0003_xyz_01', '0003_xyz_02', '0003_xyz_03']`.

Comment: @NinjaFart Ah! My apologies. I've fixed the answer - the trouble was caused by using `x` as the variable in both list comprehensions (I've changed one of the variables to `y` instead).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a more Pythonic way of doing this. But you could do it in two steps:

```
arr = ["0001_xyz_01", "0001_xyz_02" ...
highest = max([x.split('_')[0] for x in arr]
new_arr = [x for x in arr if x.startswith(highest)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> [t for t in arr if max(j[0] for j in [i.split('_') for i in arr]) in t]
['0003_xyz_01', '0003_xyz_02', '0003_xyz_03']
>>>
```

in below you can see separately that what does all of pieces of code :

```
>>> [i.split('_') for i in arr]
[['0001', 'xyz', '01'], ['0001', 'xyz', '02'], ['0001', 'xyz', '03'], ['0002', 'xyz', '01'], ['0002', 'xyz', '02'], ['0002', 'xyz', '03'], ['0003', 'xyz', '01'], ['0003', 'xyz', '02'], ['0003', 'xyz', '03']]
>>> [j[0] for j in [i.split('_') for i in arr]]
['0001', '0001', '0001', '0002', '0002', '0002', '0003', '0003', '0003']
>>> [max(j[0] for j in [i.split('_') for i in arr])]
['0003']
```